# Extracting content of <script> with Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the latitude and longitude from this page: https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/nirouth/4-bed-5-bath-twin-villa-143957/

Where it can be found in this part of the page (the Xpath of this part is /html/head/script[8]):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Residence","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","addressRegion":"Phnom Penh","addressLocality":"Chbar Ampov"},"geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":11.52,"longitude":104.95,"address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","addressRegion":"Phnom Penh","addressLocality":"Chbar Ampov"}}}</script>
```

Here's my script :

```
import scrapy

class ScrapingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scraping'
    # allowed_domains = ['https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/']

    def parse(self, response):
        lat = response.xpath('/html/head/script[8]')
        print('----------------',lat)

        yield {
           'lat': lat
        }
```

However, this Xpath yield an empty list. Is is because the content I'm looking for is in a JS script?

Comment: Try to use more specific XPath `lat = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since scrapy doesn't execute js, some `<script>` tag may be not be loaded into the page. For this reason using a index to pinpoint the element you want isn't a good idea. Better to search for something specific, my suggestion would be:

```
response.xpath('//head/script[contains(text(), "latitude")]')
```

### Edit:

The above selector will return a selector list, from it you can choose how to parse. If you want to extract the whole text in `script` you can use:

```
response.xpath('//head/script[contains(text(), "latitude")]/text()').get()
```

If you want only the latitude value, you can use a regex:

```
response.xpath('//head/script[contains(text(), "latitude")]/text()').re_first(r'"latitude":(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2})')
```

[Docs on using regex methods of Selectors.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=re_first#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.re)

Comment: That looks promising, thanks! However, how can I extract the value of "latitude" in the 'SelectorList' object that results?

Comment: @LucienS. I've edited my answer, please take a look. :)